# $L^{1} $ estimate for $2^{nd}$ order elliptic boundary value problem

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, numerical-analysis-of-pde

This is probably a classical question in numerical analysis of PDE (but I don't know the answer).

Suppose you are solving a traditional elliptic problem, for example, $u\in H^1_0(\Omega)$ (in a nice bounded domain) solves 
$$
\int_\Omega  \nabla u \cdot \nabla v = \int_\Omega F \cdot \nabla v \text{ for all } v\in H^1_0(\Omega). 
$$
Because it minimises an energy you obtain (the ambient space being of dimension 1,2 or 3) that 
$$ \int_\Omega \nabla u \cdot \nabla u \leq \int_\Omega F\cdot F 
$$ 
By considering the adjoint problem (writing $\Delta z= u$), you show that 
$$
\| u \|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2 \leq \|F \|_{L^2(\Omega)} \|F \|_{L^1(\Omega)},
$$
Which is better than what Poincaré would give if $\|F \|_{L^1(\Omega)} \ll  \|F\|_{L^2(\Omega)}$ (this is called Aubin-Nitsche  in Numerical Analysis). 
What about  the $L^1$ norm? Obviously, by Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
\|\nabla u \|_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq  \sqrt{|\Omega|}\|F\|_{L^2(\Omega)} 
$$ 
And using the embedding from $W^{-1,p}$ to $W^{1,p}_0$ for $p>1$, we obtain
$$
\|\nabla u \|_{L^p(\Omega)} \leq C(p,\Omega) \|F \|_{L^p(\Omega)}, 
$$
and therefore using Holder, 
$$ 
\|\nabla u \|_{L^1(\Omega)} \leq C(p,\Omega) \|F \|_{L^p(\Omega)}, 
$$
as well. But that does not hold for $p=1$, and I would really like an $L^1$ norm on the right-hand side...